# ajax - Extract text from html tag with display:none; with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

again, I'm have a function that extracts html by ajax, but some tag of the html in the ajax request has a style `display:none;` How can I extract the text?

In viewajax.php

```
<div id="div" style="visibility:hidden;">
<?php
$numero = mysql_num_rows($com);
echo $numero;
?>
</div>
```

In my function

```
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {

    setInterval(extr,1000);
    function extr(){
        $.ajax({
    url: "viewajax.php", 
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
    $("#h").text($(html).find("#div"));
    }
    })
    }
return false;
});
```

Comment: The text is still there, just not rendered by the browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter if the element has the display set to none, as DOM traversal methods aren't dependent on the elements visibility.

Of course, this is a syntax error :

```
$("#h").text($(html).find("#div"));
```

and should be just (ID's are unique):

```
$(html).find("#div").text();
```

if `#div` is not a child but a root element, you'd do:

```
$(html).filter("#div").text();
```

Comment: Yes, but if i don't set display:none, it appears normal

Comment: Set whatever you like, it doesn't matter, jQuery will get the text anyway.

Comment: let me see if i understand, i set: $("#h").text($("#div").text());

Comment: Yes, that should work, but you would have to find `#div` in the returned markup, which in your example is `html`, so `$('#h').text( $(html).find("#div").text() )`

Comment: yeah, finally you had the reason: $("#h").text($(html).filter("#div").text());

Comment: Yes, this: $("#h").text($(html).filter("#div").text()); solves my problem, thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Check Your CSS style  , or CSS through jQuery that might be affect to this ..
Ajax request does not affect this type of problem to any DOM ..